# Collector voltage for this transistor circuit

Tags: transistors

For the circuit below, $$β = 80 \quad and \quad  V_{BE} = 0.7\;V$$

[image]

I applied KVL to the closed loop on the left -base-emittor loop- and the bigger closed loop on the right -collector-emittor loop- (just the bigger rectangle on the right). **I thought that V0 would be equal to the voltage between GND and the wire that the upper 10k is connected to, which is V subscript CE.**

So from the first loop I mentioned,
$$-1+120\times10^3I_B+V_{BE}=0$$
$$-1+120\times10^3I_B+0.7=0$$
$$120\times10^3I_B=0.3$$

Thus,
$$I_B=2.5\times10^{-6}\,A=2.5\,μA$$

From the equality
$$I_C=βI_B$$
$$I_C=80\times2.5\times10^{-6}\,A=0.2\,mA$$

Applying KVL to the second loop I mentioned above,
$$-V_0-10\times10^3I_C+20=0$$
$$-V_0-10\times10^3\times0.2\times10^{-3}+20=0$$
$$V_0=-2\,V+20\,V=18\,V$$

Thus,
$$I_0=\frac{V_0}{10\,kΩ}$$
$$I_0=\frac{18\,V}{10\,kΩ} =\,1.8\,mA$$

But the book says
$$V_0=12\,V \;and\; I_0=600\,μA$$

I found some people saying the book is wrong, but I wonder about the answer, and

- How would you solve this?
- Is the sentence in **bold** (above) true?

Comment: With *no transistor*, Vo is 10 volts. Collector current pulls Vo toward ground. The usual practice is to reference all voltages to ground, as you suggest.

Comment: It is better to give each resistor and voltage source a name and insert the values at the last moment.

Comment: Even if a book fails to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, at just first glance the answer is wrong - if \$I_0 = 600\,µA\$ then \$V_0 = I_0 * 10\,kΩ= 6\,V\$;   \$6\,V\ !=\ 12\,V\$ so the answers are contradicting.

Here is the solution:

Base current is what you calculated: \$ I_b = 2.5 * 10^{-6}\,A\$

Collector current: \$ I_b*\beta = 2 * 10^{-4}\,A\$

Now \$ V_0 \$ is simply: \$ 20\,V - i10^4\,Ω \$ (\$i\$ is the current of the top most resistor)

Currents equation: \$i = i_c + i_0 \$   (\$ i_c\$ is collector current)

Next we put current equation into \$V_0\$ equation:
\$V_0 = 20\,V - (i_c + i_0)10^4\,Ω\$

\$I_0\$ is \$ \frac{V_0}{10^4}\$

So we combine above three equations into: \$V_0 = 20\,V - (i_c + \frac{V_0}{10^4\,Ω})10^4\,Ω \$

\$2V_0 = 20\,V - i_c*10^4\,Ω\$

\$V_0 = 9\,V \$

and finally

\$I_0 = \frac{9\,V}{10^4\,Ω} = 900\,µA \$

Comment: Yes, that was what I'd done to check the answer too. ^^

Comment: Oh, then my mistake was that I just had considered \$I_C\$ to be the current through the top most 10k resistor, I hadn't thought that it would be \$I_0+I_C\$. Everything is clear now. :)

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you do is rewrite the problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe6j2R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's done by simply performing the usual Thevenin equivalent on \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ and the voltage applied across them to compose a new Thevenin voltage source of \$10\:\text{V}\$ and Thevenin resistance of \$5\:\text{k}\Omega\$. At this point, it's quite obvious that the output cannot be more than this Thevenin voltage.

The base current is \$I_\text{B}=\frac{1\:\text{V}-700\:\text{mV}}{120\:\text{k}\Omega}=2.5\:\mu\text{A}\$. With \$\beta=80\$, this says that \$I_\text{C}=80\cdot 2.5\:\mu\text{A}=200\:\mu\text{A}\$. The drop across the Thevenin resistance (\$R_4\$ above) is \$200\:\mu\text{A}\cdot 5\:\text{k}\Omega=1\:\text{V}\$.

Therefore, the output will be \$1\:\text{V}\$ below the Thevenin voltage of \$10\:\text{V}\$, or \$V_\text{O}=9\:\text{V}\$.

---

You can separately analyze it by using KCL at the collector node, using the value of \$I_\text{C}\$ computed earlier (see above):

$$\frac{V_\text{O}-20\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{O}}{R_2}+I_\text{C}=0\:\text{A}$$

That solves out as \$V_\text{O}=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot\left(20\:\text{V}-R_1\cdot I_\text{C}\right)\$

And it gets you the exact same answer.

From there it is quite easy to work out the requested current.

---

Yes, the book is wrong if that is what it said.

Comment: +1 for thevenin method. Btw, you have mistake in base current - in the denominator you have 1k while it is 120k Ohm.

Comment: Well, I have a question. I understood why the Thevenin resistance became 5k but I couldn't really get why that 20V would become 10V as the Thevenin voltage. Can you please explain?

Comment: @AndréYuhai The Thevenin voltage is the voltage that would appear at the mid-point if the mid-point is unloaded. I think you can see that this would be 10 V.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is wrong. Suppose there isn´t a transistor in the circuit and it´s only both 10 kΩ resistors. Then V<sub>o</sub> = 10 V in this situation.

Adding anything in parallel to it will cause that equivalent resistance to decrease, so it´s impossible to have V<sub>o</sub> = 12 V, since V<sub>o</sub> <= 10 V

As you´ve already figured out I<sub>c</sub> = 0.2 mA, then you can apply KVL to both resistors as a loop as follows: 20 - 10 kΩ(I<sub>o</sub> + 0.2 mA) - 10 kΩ*I<sub>o</sub> = 0.

Solve for I<sub>o</sub>, and I<sub>o</sub> = 0.9 mA, and as a result, V<sub>o</sub> = 0.9 mA * 10 kΩ = 9 V

Comment: Then my answer \$V_0=18V\$ is wrong too.

Comment: @AndréYuhai yes, unfortunately it cannot be greater than 10v.

I´ll edit my answer and post the way I did